# Correction for non-normal residuals where residuals are not correlated or show heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, outliers, residuals, normality-assumption, neweywest

I know the implication of non-normal residuals is uncertain statistical tests because the SEs are inefficient.  Can I apply the Newey-West to calculate standardized Standard Errors for an OLS regression in response to non-normal residuals? I have outliers that cannot be captured by the OLS regression using a prescribed set of potential drivers.

Will the Newey-West correction give me appropriate P-values, even if the model does not suffer from heteroskedasticity or serially-correlated residuals?

Comment: The Newey-West SEs are for heteroscedasticity &/or autocorrelation, not for non-normality. If you don't have enough data to trust the central limit theorem, you may want to bootstrap or move to a nonparametric approach.

Comment: Box-Cox transformation?

Comment: @JohnK That will change the model from positing a linear relationship between the variables to one with a non-linear relationship.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes but it will bring the response variable closer to  normality which is often desirable. There is no free lunch.

Comment: Is there any Method for adjusting Standard Errors and P-Values from a model with non-normal resides so that statistical tests are reliable?  (Without respecifying the model).